# ¿Como puedo usar el Cache de nextJS para actualizar una Pagina dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, fetch, nextjs

quería ver si alguien me ayuda porque no consigo que los datos se actualicen automáticamente. La página que intento actualizar es:

[image: Portada APP]

Y aquí esta el código, abajo del código explico alguna cosa importante.

```js
import NoEKEY from "@/components/dash/NoEKEY"
import ServerInfoComponent from "@/components/dash/Serverinfo"

const loadData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/erlc/server`, { cache: 'no-store' })

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }

    const useData = await res.json()
    console.log(useData)
    return useData
}

async function HomeDashPage() {
    const error = ""

    let data = await loadData()

    return (
        <div>
            <ServerInfoComponent data={data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeDashPage
```

Este código es el que coge los datos y esa parte funciona perfectamente, los datos cargan, el problema es que yo quiero actualizarlos sin tener que actualizar la pagina manualmente.

Si se preguntan porque le puse que no lo guarde en cache, es porque debido a eso no actualiza ni recargando manualmente, porque guarda los datos.

Agradecería si alguien me puede ayudar un poco. GRACIAS.

Comment: El fetch de nextjs tiene una opción para revalidar ¿Que has intentado para no tener que actualizar la pagina manualmente?

Comment: La revalidación no me funciona, no actualiza los datos.